# Android Studio Reading php

Tags: java, php

My android app needs to take string from this site http://oklagija.net/rss.php
I looked all over the internet, but none of solutions worked for me. I can read from .xml files and others, but it is not working on .php
If you have any piece of code that actually worked on .php, please help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to export the strings of the site using a php class  `SimpleXMLElement();`
check this **[link](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)**